# MSBuild failed to create .xap when building cordova-wp7 for debugging - CORDOVA WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8, msbuild, cordova-3

I've already found this question here [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669292/msbuild-failed-to-create-xap-when-building-cordova-wp8-for-debugging) and here [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746069/phonegap-3-3-0-wp8-project-giving-msbuild-error)

But none of the solutions worked for me. I tried all of them.

I'm using windows 7, windows phone emulator 7.1 is installed on VS 2010, .NET framework 4 and cordova 3.

Already faced many problems while installing wp7 in cordova. now stuck with this while build.Following line giving me the error

`cordova build wp7`

Found error

> Error: An error occurred while building the wp7 project.ERROR:MSBuild
>   failed to create .xap when building cordova-wp7 for debugging.

I tried **VS power shell** as suggested in solutions, didn't work.

Now question is how can I solve this? Is there any easy way to try cordova for windows phone. I'm getting frustrated to see this much problems. I didn't face this much problems to use other platforms with Cordova. Do I've to use updated stuff like VS 2013 or windows phone 8? I don't to update right now. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake i did when I faced this error was,I didnt include all files to the copy to output directory.Just click on individual project files,you will have the properties window visible for that particular.Just set **copy to output directory** property as **Always copy**.Now files will be included. Make sure to do this for all necessary files including images.

Just refer to see more on this property http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d76869a-7d8a-425d-a38e-ba72a8e549b9/visual-studio-2012-express-images-dont-get-compiledcopied

I hope this solves your issue.It did for me