# Failed to to create .xap when building cordova-wp8 for debugging

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, msbuild, visual-studio-cordova

I have Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I installed Cordova tooling in it to create packages from VS (from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675)

I see some "solutions" on the internet like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669292/msbuild-failed-to-create-xap-when-building-cordova-wp8-for-debugging) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746069/phonegap-3-3-0-wp8-project-giving-msbuild-error) but nothing's work for me.

When I build my projects for iOS or Android, everything's fine but for windows it fails; i get this error: Error    2   **MSBuild failed to create .xap when building cordova-wp8 for debugging.**

Do you have any idea to help me?

Comment: run app on release mode

Comment: Got this: Error 2 The command ""C:\Users\pauline\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows Phone" --configuration "Release" --projectDir . --projectName "appTestMulti" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "PhoneEmulatorWvga512"" exited with code 8.

Answer (score 0):

Building for Windows or WP8 requires you to have installed the right SDK. To verify these are installed, open Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs -> Visual Studio 2013, choose "Change" and "Modify" then check the packages:

- Tools for maintaining Store apps for Win 8
- Windows Phone 8.0 SDK

*Taken from the official [documentation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397716)

Comment: The SDK is installed including the 2 packages you quoted

Comment: Could you open your Hyper-V manager and see if an emulator image  WinPhone exists in the list?